# How to get value from custom dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

guys. I made a custom dropdown list, but can't get its value right.

So basically I need to save the value of a chosen dropdown element and use it in the form along with other data.

Any ideas how to fix this?

```
<form method="post" action="/subscribed.php">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="name" placeholder="Name" name="name" id="name" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Your email" name="email" id="email" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="hidden" name="data-value" id="data-value">
      <div class="wrapper-demo">
        <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-3" tabindex="1">
          <span>Option</span>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="option1" data-value="option1">option1</a></li>
            <li><a href="option2" data-value="option2">option2</a></li>
            <li><a href="option3" data-value="option3">option3</a></li>
            <li><a href="option4" data-value="option4">option4</a></li>
            <li><a href="option5" data-value="option5">option5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      function DropDown(el) {
        this.dd = el;
        this.placeholder = this.dd.children('span');
        this.opts = this.dd.find('ul.dropdown > li');
        this.val = '';
        this.index = -1;
        this.initEvents();
      }
      DropDown.prototype = {
        initEvents : function() {
        var obj = this;
        obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
          $(this).toggleClass('active');
          return false;
        });
      obj.opts.on('click',function(e){
        var opt = $(this);
        var el = e.target;
        obj.val = opt.text();
        obj.index = opt.index();
        obj.placeholder.text(el.getAttribute("data-value"));
        $('data-value').val(el.getAttribute("data-value"));
        });
        },
      getValue : function() {
        return this.val;
      },
      getIndex : function() {
        return this.index;
      }
      }
      $(function() {
        var dd = new DropDown( $('#dd') );
        $(document).click(function() {
      // all dropdowns
      $('.wrapper-dropdown-3').removeClass('active');
      });
      });
      </script>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: fix what? you haven't mentioned what is or isn't working as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using `$('data-value')` that is wrong selector, use `$('#data-value')`,

if you are selecting using id then put # before that. `$('#elementid');`

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0x8gq6L5/)